# How to set role name in prefix dynamically for same route group in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, roles, prefix

I want to create dynamic prefix name according to logged user role name like for a same route group
if admin is login in admin panel then
url like :

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/dashboard
```

And, if dealer is login in admin panel :

```
http://localhost:8000/dealer/dashboard
```

my route group is

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'verified', 'preventBackHistory']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

Basically My route group is same for admin & dealer
when i want different prefix according to user role when user is successfully login

Comment: Welcome to SO ... just have both groups, there is no need for routes to be dynamic in this way

Comment: But my only need is to change prefix only , all other things are same for admin & dealer

Comment: how is the user getting directed to this route?

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is making a few assumptions about what you are doing.

You are not going to have access to the information about the current user until after the routes have been registered. The session has not started until after the request has been dispatched to a route and passes through the Middleware stack which will start the session. This is an idea of how to achieve that in a way that makes sense for the order of events.

You should setup the route group with a dynamic prefix:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{roleBased}', 'as' => 'admin.', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'verified', 'dealWithPrefix', 'preventBackHistory']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

Then in the `RouteServiceProvider` you will be adding a constraint for the prefix, parameter `roleBased`, to only allow it to be `admin` or `client`:

```
public function boot()
{
    // restrict the prefix to only be 'admin' or 'dealer'
    \Route::pattern('roleBased', 'admin|dealer');

    parent::boot();
}
```

Now you will have to create a middleware to deal with getting the information of the current user to set a default for this prefix so that any URLs you generate to these routes will have this prefix and you don't have to pass a parameter for it. We will also remove the prefix parameter from the route so it does not get passed to your actions:

```
public function handle($request, $next)
{
    $role = $request->user()->role; // hopefully 'admin' | 'client'

    // setting the default for this parameter for the current user's role
    \URL::defaults([
        'roleBased' => $role
    ]);

    // to stop the router from passing this parameter to the actions
    $request->route()->forgetParameter('roleBased');
    
    return $next($request);
}
```

Register this middleware in your kernel as `dealWithPrefix`. Note in the route group above this middleware was added to the list of middleware.

If you need to generate URLs to any routes in that group, and the current request isn't one of the routes in that group, you will be required to pass a parameter for this prefix when generating the URL:

```
route('admin.home', ['roleBased' => ...]);
```

If the request is currently for one of the routes in that group you will not need to add this parameter:

```
route('admin.home');
```

Note: This middleware could be applied in a wider way but you would need to know what default you want to use for this parameter if someone wasn't logged in. This is also assuming you may have more than just 1 route in that route group. If it is only that one single route then this can probably be adjusted slightly.

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal php file, so you may just add

```
if(...){ // if admin
    $prefix = 'admin';
}else{ // if dealer
    $prefix = 'dealer';
}
```

before your routes, and in your routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => $prefix, 'as' => $prefix.'.', 'namespace' => ucwords($prefix), 'middleware' => ['auth', 'verified', 'preventBackHistory']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

Comment: they would not be able to use route caching if they had conditionals in their routes like this, as what ever condition was met when caching the routes would be the route that is cached